# Install Windows 10 on Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (Ubuntu)

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, dell, virtualization, windows-10

I have some experience with linux command line and figure it's time to immerse myself. I am purchasing an XPS developer edition (Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS installed) with 256gb hard drive and 8gb RAM. I still need Windows for certain programs, so I am wondering the best way to implement that? Would it be best to run it through a virtual machine? I can obtain a copy of windows 10 through my university. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be best to run it through a virtual machine?

That would be my method: keep windows sandboxed and make backups of your VMs. Those backups as easy to make and easy to automate. Plus a copy of the VM and you have 2 Windows.

When you run into problems (cryptolocker, virus, etc) just restore a clean backup.

256Gb is a SSD I would assume? If not... try to replace it with an SSD.

Comment: Yes it is an ssd. As far as using a VM, any recommendations? I was planning on using VirtualBox.

Comment: vmware or vbox does not really matter. I like vbox more myself.